# Parse reponse qnamaker

Tags: c#, azure-qna-maker

I try to create a card or show some pictures from qnamaker response but it's unclear.

The response I get is as below:

```
A new way to interact
[FIND OUT MORE](https://xxxx/concept/)

![Img 821](https://www.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/business.jpg)
```

Is there a library in c# provided by Microsoft to parse the response or is there a way to it?

Thanks,

Comment: Its looking like markdown content, try using a [`markdown parser`](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig) for C#

Comment: Wow. It did the trick. Thanks a lot

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Go ahead and put this in an answer so that Dalton5 can accept it